# In pandas, how to collect data in all rows and make new data into a single row?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have the following data frame called `data_frame`:

```
      a         b       c
0   [1, 2]   [3, 4]   [5, 6]
1   [7, 8]   [9, 10]  [11, 12]
2   [13, 14] [15, 16] [17, 18]
```

What I want to do is element-wise mean of list in all rows. For instance, the result data should be:

```
                   a                                    b                                      c
0 [(1 + 7 + 13) / 3, (2 + 8 + 14) / 3] [(3 + 9 + 15) / 3, (4 + 10 + 16) / 3] [(5 + 11 + 17) / 3, (6 + 12 + 18) / 3]
```

If each element in pandas was a single value, this could be done by `data_frame.mean()`.

However, how can it be done if each element in pandas is the list shown above?

Comment: There are alwyas list with same length, here `2` ?

Comment: will the list length for a column be same for all rows?

Comment: @jezrael All rows in each column have the same length of the list, but each column has a different length of the list.

Comment: @Shijith All rows in each column have the same length of the list, but each column has a different length of the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert for each column values to `2d array`s, then use `mean` and last convert Series to one row `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.array(x.tolist()).mean(axis=0).tolist()).to_frame().T
print (df)
            a            b             c
0  [7.0, 8.0]  [9.0, 10.0]  [11.0, 12.0]
```

Another solution, very similar principe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.array(df[x].tolist()).mean(axis=0).tolist() for x in df.columns]], 
                   columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `stack()` then get mean of level 1 and aggregate back as list/join (anything you prefer):

```
s = df.stack()
pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index).mean(level=1).agg(list,1).to_frame().T
```

---

```
        a        b         c
0  [7, 8]  [9, 10]  [11, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Summary of the code below : 

 [Transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) dataframe and convert to numpy array

 zip the entries in each sublist/array ... this pairs the numbers together... so for `a`, we'll have (1,7,13), (2,8,14); same thing for b and c

 for each zipped entry, find the mean

 create a dictionary where the outcome is paired with the columns

 create the dataframe

```
data = {"a":[[1,2],[7,8],[13,14]], "b":[[3,4],[9,10],[15,16]], "c":[[5,6],[11,12],[17,18]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

outcome = [[np.mean(entry) for entry in (zip(*ent))]
           for ent in df.T.to_numpy()]

pd.DataFrame({key:[value] for key, value in zip(df.columns, outcome)})

            a              b         c
    0   [7.0, 8.0]  [9.0, 10.0] [11.0, 12.0]
```